# How to define an class instance on a tuple of lists?

Tags: haskell

Say I have some class:

```
class Foo t where
 foo :: t a -> a
 bar :: t a -> a
```

and I want to define an instance like so:

```
instance Foo ([a],[a]) where
 foo = head . fst
 bar = head . snd
```

This gives me the error:

```
main.hs:31:15: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘([a], [a])’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Foo’, namely ‘([a], [a])’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Foo ([a], [a])’
   |
31 | instance Foo ([a],[a]) where
   |
```

I tried the following (with `TypeSynonymInstances`):

```
type ListFoo a = ([a],[a])
instance Foo ListFoo where
 foo = head . fst
 bar = head . snd
```

I think a `newtype` would solve it, but that would make the instance code significantly more complex. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you need a `newtype` declaration (or `data`, but `newtype` makes more sense). I don't see how it would make the code "significantly more complex" - it's just one extra function to compose with in both method implementations.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yeah that's what I ended up doing (`data` actually). Well it's simple in this simplified example, the actual code had a few more functions. The real reason was that I had already written the code using a type synonym. Now that I think about it though, it was probably more work to write up this question than to just rewrite it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond FWIW I would guess that `data` makes more sense here most of the time. `data ListFoo a = ListFoo {foos, bars :: [a]}`, rather than newtype-wrapping a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to write that instance for the exact type you specified, but there is an isomorphic type in `base` that you can define it on: `Product [] []`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Functor.Product

instance Foo (Product [] []) where
 foo (Pair x _) = head x
 bar (Pair _ y) = head y
```

The reason that you need to use `Product` instead of `(,)` is that in the same way that you have `instance Functor Maybe` and not `instance Functor (Maybe a)`, your type constructor needs to take a type as a parameter, not to just have some type variable in it.